# PDE that are unchanged under all axis-rotations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

It is exactly the same question as [Partial Differential Equation about Rotation question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286431/partial-differential-equation-about-rotation-question). Sadly, I gain nothing useful from the above post. Or I should say I am not familiar with the terms in the question and I have no idea what approach should I use.

> Consider the constant coefficient PDE $$a_{11}u_{xx}+2a_{12}u_{xy}+a_{22}u_{yy}+b_{1}u_{x}+b_{2}u_{y}+cu=0.$$ Show that the only ones that are unchanged under all axis-rotations (rotation invariant) have the form $$a(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) + bu = 0,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

*It is a homework problem.* So I would appreciate hints and clarification rather than the complete solution.

My understanding of the question:

After a suitable change of variables, if the given PDE becomes $a(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) + bu = 0$, then it would be rotation invariant.

**But then, what change of variable should I consider? I also notice that there is a '2' in front of $a_{12}$, which somehow reminds me of symmetric matrix. Is it useful?**

Answer (score -1):

You can consider the symmetric matrix B satisfies $BAB^{T} = diag(λ1, λ2)$

Visit https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math4220/Suggested%20Solution%20to%20Assignment%201_MATH4220.pdf